# Expand a bootstrap 4 collapsed menu with direct access

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-4

I have a sidebar menu with many entries and many sublevels, which looks like that :

```
  <div class="container-fluid">
     <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-2" id="sidebar" style="margin: 5px 0">
           <div class="list-group panel">
              <a href="/demo" class="list-group-item">Menu</a>
              <a href="#tech" class="list-group-item" data-toggle="collapse"><i class="fa fa-wrench"></i> Menu 1 <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i></a>
              <div class="collapse" id="tech" data-parent="#sidebar">
                 <a href="#techsub1" class="list-group-item" data-toggle="collapse">Sub 1 <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i></a>
                 <div class="collapse" id="techsub1" data-parent="#techsub1">
                    <a class="list-group-item" href="techsub1sub1.html">techsub1sub1</a>
                    <a class="list-group-item" href="techsub1sub2.html">techsub1sub2</a>
                 </div>

                 <a href="#techsub2" class="list-group-item" data-toggle="collapse">Sub 2 <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i></a>
                 <div class="collapse" id="techsub2" data-parent="#techsub2">
                    <a href="#techsub2sub1" class="list-group-item" data-toggle="collapse">Sub 2 <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i></a>
                    <div class="collapse" id="techsub2sub1" data-parent="#techsub2sub1">
                       <a class="list-group-item" href="techsub2sub1sub1.html">techsub2sub1sub1</a>
                       <a class="list-group-item" href="techsub2sub1sub2.html">techsub2sub1sub2</a>
                    </div>
                 </div>
              </div>

              <a href="#anx" class="list-group-item" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#sidebar"><i class="fa fa-book"></i> Menu 2 <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i></a>
              <div class="collapse" id="anx" data-parent="#sidebar">
                 <a class="list-group-item" href="anx1.html">anx1</a>
                 <a class="list-group-item" href="anx2.html">anx2</a>
              </div>

           </div>
        </div>

        <main class="col-md-10" style="background-color: #fff; max-width: 1140px; padding-top: 30px; padding-bottom: 20px">
           Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
        </main>
     </div>
  </div>
```

It works well but there are so many entries in the menu that I want to use a pager on each page [Previous - Current - Next]

My concern is that when I click on Previous or Next page, the sidebar is collapsed. Is there a way to expand the according page called, but keeping it collapsed on the home page ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need to do is to add a `.show` CSS class to the collapsed (having `.collapse` CSS class) block, which you want to be expanded. See https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/collapse/

It can be done in two basic ways - **hard-coded** for each page or **added dynamically/programmatically** based on some parameter (probably `id` of desired expanded collapse)

Passing a parameter from one to other page on redirecting is a separate question, but in case you wonder how to do it - try some URL parameters/hash or cookies/local storage

Comment: James, I was probably not clear enough. As an example, I don't know how to identify that #techsub2 has to be shown when techsub2sub1sub2.html is retreived

Comment: OIC, sorry for misinterpretation.
In case jQuery is available, does `$('#sidebar a[href="techsub2sub1sub2.html"]').parents('.collapse').addClass('show');` work for your example with `#techsub2` as intended?
Notice, the key attribute is the retrieved page URL from the anchor

Comment: Brillant ! Thank you so much James